# How to prevent any two elements from being the same in a random draw?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-statements

Here is my code: (Thank you MurifoX)

```
<% random_bullets = Bullet.all %>
<ul>
  <% 4.times do %>
    <li><%= random_bullets.sample.content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I would like to know if making a condition is possible to prevent any two "bullets" from having the same content on the page. If so, could I get some help on the issue, maybe a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried the shuffle method i posted in your other question?

Comment: I have, it's not returning errors (thankfully), but it is showing only a 1-line white row where the bullets used to be.

Comment: MurifoX it is working now, my database had truncated without my knowlege of it doing so, and it's working perfectly. I can't thank you enough, and I've voted up your answer (as I got 15 rep now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove them from the pool as they are used:

```
<% 4.times do %>
  <li><%= random_bullets.delete_at(rand random_bullets.size).content %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: May I ask why you remove .sample? EDIT: That and it doesn't work with the code.

Comment: You don't need `Array#sample`, which selects a random element from the array and returns it. You need to *remove and return* an element from the array, which `Array#delete_at` does, and with a little assist from `rand` it'll be a random element. Code should work now, I did have some mistakes in it (was confusing `Hash#delete` with `Array#delete_at`).

Comment: Returns this error 'undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: Only if `random_bullets` is an empty array. Do you have more than 4 items in the array?

Comment: All I can really tell you is I have more than 4 rows with content inside them inside the database.

Comment: Still nothing, ismaelga. MurifoX's answers so far have worked the most, but I'm sure a little tweaking will further perfect them. I just need them to display their content now.